spring secury xml config for webservice SOAP basic authentication
my goal is to expose web service soaps (post) under basic authentication (it is sufficient that the credentials are fixed and noted in the xml).
I tried to configure the xml as follows but when I make a request (without auth or with incorrect credentials) the webservice responds with 200.
    <http use-expressions="true">
 <!--       <intercept-url pattern="/services/pricews" access="isAuthenticated()" method="GET"/>  -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')" method="POST" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>
     
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


I'm sure that the xml file is used by my application because I have the evidence on the logs if I wrong configure the xml.
what wrong?
I also tried:
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" method="POST"/> 
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated" method="POST"/>

without success.
I tried to specify/don't specify the method (also with GET, ...) and also I tried a specific address for the pattern instead of the the universal '/**'.
What the difference between "isAuthenticated()" and "authenticated"?
ps. I want use only xml config file, not java notation.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright (c) 2021 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company. All rights reserved.
-->
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />


    <!-- <http pattern="/WEB-INF/500.jsp" security="none" /> -->
    <!-- <http pattern="/WEB-INF/404.jsp" security="none" /> -->
    <!-- <http pattern="/static/**" security="none" /> -->

    <http pattern="/securityNone"  security="none"/>


<!-- method="POST" 


    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" logout-url="/logout" />
        <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login"
            password-parameter="password" username-parameter="username" />
    </http>
-->

    <http use-expressions="true">
 <!--       <intercept-url pattern="/services/pricews" access="isAuthenticated()" method="GET"/>  -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')" method="POST" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>
     
    
<!--    <http use-expressions="true" > -->
<!--        <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="authenticated" method="POST"/>  -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" method="POST"/> 

<!--        <http-basic /> -->
<!--    </http> -->

<!-- -->
<!-- 
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/services/pricews" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

-->

    <!-- <http use-expressions="true"> -->
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> -->
    <!-- <http-basic /> -->
    <!-- </http> -->


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


  </beans:beans>


can you provide your full xml file (whats the encoding you are using for your password )! and for your question : "isAuthenticated()" is a Spring Security expression that checks if the user is authenticated."authenticated" is an attribute value used in older versions of Spring Security.

@Mohamedaminebenhassen full xml provided. Consider that I attempt several test, so, the xml don't is clean, and now this configuration is in a sleeping branch
